# Get appid for push Notification - phone gap (android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, push-notification

```
pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "xxxx", appid: "?" },
    function (status) {
        var pushToken = status;
        console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
    },
    function (status) {
        console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
    }
);
```

What to put in place a question mark (how get appid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appid = application code from this site **[pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/)**

singing to this site and create new app, get the app code! :]

Comment: yeah only first 1,000,000 device for 10 applications ;)  http://www.pushwoosh.com/accounts-comparison/

Comment: check this link ;) 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/